# How to add a global transaction filter in play/scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to set up a global filter to add transactionality to my entire app.

```
object TransactionFilter extends Filter {
    def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
        next(request)
    }
}
```

I'm using squeryl, which uses blocks like so: transaction { ... }

```
object TransactionFilter extends Filter {
    def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
        transaction { next(request) }
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work either, because it's only adding transactionality to the generation of the Future[SimpleResult].

I need the execution of the Future[SimpleResult] to be wrapped in a transaction { ... } block.

How do I do this? I have searched and searched.

On a side note, I'm not interested in using action composition for this, I've already got that working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
object TransactionFilter extends Filter {
  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    // Begin transaction
    val tx = beginTx

    // Do the work
    val f = next(request)

    // Commit on success
    f onSuccess {
      case result => commitTx(tx)
    }

    // Rollback on failure
    f onFailure {
      case t => rollbackTx(tx)
    }

    f
  }

  def beginTx: Int = 42
  def commitTx(tx: Int) = {}
  def rollbackTx(tx: Int) = {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem I'm having with this though is that I can't seem to get squeryl to do transactions this way. I tried something similar to your code, using bindToCurrentThread, but I still got the same errors. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Don't bind anything to thread. In Play (and Akka) you don't know which thread is handling which future. It seems that you create a transaction in one thread, but then you try to close it in another thread and that doesn't work.

Comment: I figured that was the problem. I'm now creating a new session: "var session = Session.currentSessionOption.getOrElse(SessionFactory.newSession)" and I'm getting intermittent "No session is bound to current thread" errors.

Comment: So is there no way for me to just tack on the initialization of the session to the execution of the future itself? What I have now will work, it's pulled straight from Squeryl's source code for the transaction { ... } method. But it needs to be executed in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use slick 2.0 instead of squeryl.

In slick2 the TheadLocal session is renamed dynamic session and is not the default behaviour. The default one is an implicit session that can be used without problems with Futures